# Spaces being lost in RTF document after replace in Coldfusion

Tags: replace, coldfusion, space, rtf

I am reading a file in Coldfusion and replacing some variables in the document formatted [var1] with the results from a query.

The replacing works fine BUT some of the spaces before and after the variable get lost when we view the final document saved and so the text doesnt read well.
The document only has some items highlighted in bold in terms of formatting.

Has anyone come across this before? If so what's the solution?

Thanks

```
<cfset pathToRTF                    =  expandpath("#_filelocation##Evaluate("_#form.template#")#") />
<cfset filename                     = _sname & "_" & _fname & "_" & GetFileFromPath(pathToRTF) />
<cfset e_email_VariableList         = "">
<cfset e_email_VariableListValues   = "">    
<cfset rtf                          = FileRead(pathToRTF) />

<cfset final_rtf                    = "">
<cfset rtfreplaced                  = rtf>
<cfloop list="#admin_members_variables_replace#" index="iRep" delimiters=",">
    <cfset varName                  = "[#trim(iRep)#]" />
    <cfset varValue                 = "  " & Evaluate("_#trim(iRep)#") & "  " />

    <cfif find(varName,rtf)>
        <cfset rtf                  = replaceNoCase(rtf, varName, varValue,"ALL") />
    </cfif>
    </cfloop>
<cfset final_rtf = rtf>
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="filename=#filename#.doc" />
<cfcontent type="application/msword"><cfoutput>#final_rtf#</cfoutput>
```

** UPDATE: example RTF file as requested https://launch.box.com/s/bqbe0ipwla9w5wpvg0hdfxjni7hezy39

Comment: You're doing a trim in there, which is going to kill some spaces, is it not?

Comment: the trim if for the variable name as its in a list. The spaces that are lost happen outside the variable name in square brackets, e.g. "the [var1]" becomes "thewoman" instead of "the woman"

Comment: Could you provide an example RTF?

Comment: example RTF file as requested https://launch.box.com/s/bqbe0ipwla9w5wpvg0hdfxjni7hezy39

Comment: Code works for me (tested with CF10). It replaces and surrounds the placeholder with two spaces. Do you have whitespace management of any sort?

Comment: in Railo web i have "Simple whitespace management - every whitespace character that follows whitespace is removed" selected. Shall i change the option to "no whitespace management"?